# Proving $ \lim_{x\to 2} x^2 = 4$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove the following limit but I am a stuck at a step.

$$ \lim_{x\to 2} x^2 = 4$$

Proof : Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. We want to find a $\delta > 0$ such thant $0<|x-2|<\delta \rightarrow |x^2-4|<\varepsilon$

$$ |x^2-4| < \varepsilon$$
$$ |x-2||x+2| < \varepsilon$$

What do I do from here ?

Comment: The next step is usually to declare "I would never choose a $\delta$ that is greater than $1$". That lets you get at least some grip on the $|x+2|$ term.

Comment: It is a known fact that $x^2$ (and any other polynomial) is continuous. Or do you want a more basic proof?

Comment: @tatan Obviously he wants a more basic proof. It's also known that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, why do you think that is?

Comment: @Ed_4434 Probably, I am a real fool to ask such a question to the OP :)

Answer (score 2):

You could **choose** that $\;\delta<\frac12\;$ , say, and then

$$|x-2|<\delta\iff 2-\delta<x<2+\delta\implies \frac72=4-\delta<x+2<4+\delta=\frac92$$

so that you get

$$|x-2||x+2|<|x-2|\cdot\frac92<\frac{9\delta}2\color{red}{<\epsilon}\iff \delta<\frac{2\epsilon}9$$

and thus **for any** $\;\epsilon>0\;$ , choosing $\;\delta=\min\left\{\frac12,\,\frac{2\epsilon}9\right\}\;$ you get what you want.

Observe that "the choosing" of $\;\delta\;$ that we began with is rather arbitrary. You could as well have *chosen* $\;\delta<1\;,\;\;\delta<0.001\;$ or whatever. We usually choose something more or less nice, though.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Choose $\delta= \epsilon$, then we see that
\begin{align}
|x^2-4| = |x-2||x+2| \leq \epsilon |x+2|< \epsilon(4+\epsilon)
\end{align}
whenever $|x-2|<\delta$.

Comment: But $\epsilon(4+\epsilon)$ isn't less than $\epsilon$, so you haven't proven anything.

Comment: @Arthur one could easily set $\epsilon(4+\epsilon)=\epsilon'$ which is why I called my answer a hint.

Comment: So say what you really mean: choose $\delta$ so that $\delta(\delta+4)<\epsilon$. Anything else makes this answer a confusing one to people not used to $\epsilon$-$\delta$. In fact, it was confusing me, initially, and I'm teaching this stuff right now.